# Which process is calling the syscall in Linux kernel?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, trace, system-calls

This seems pretty basic - tracing a syscall to a user call - but I couldn't find any answer to that.

We are running some Linux Kernel code that measures frequent syscalls.
When the frequency is above the threshold, I am printing out the kernel back-trace.
What's missing is the association to the user process back-trace for the syscall.
So basically what I need is some method of checking from the syscall (in kernel mode), which user process (and function) is calling it.

Here's the kernel backtrace:

```
do_gettimeofday+0x43/0xc0
compat_sys_time+0x10/0x40
sysenter_do_call+0x1b/0x67
```

How do I find which process was is calling the syscall?
Which state is the process in?
Can I use some ptrace/strace mechanism to achieve that?
Is this information available in the kernel stack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `current` structure will give you information of the currently executing task. You could keep track of the current structure pointer or the pid (`current->pid`).

The full definition of the task struct can be found in [*include/linux/sched.h*](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1026).

The generic declaration for `current` can be found in [*include/asm-generic/current.h*](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/current.h#L7).